# Obtener el string mas corto de una array

Tags: javascript, array, string

Estoy intentando en un ejercicio el "return" del string que tenga menos caracteres dentro de un array. No estoy seguro de que sea con `Math.min()`, también he estado viendo con `getMinX()`, pero no doy con la tecla.

```
findMinLengthOfThreeWords = () => {

    var index = ['a', 'be', 'see'];

    var result = Math.min(index.length);
    
    return result;
};
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Si es un ejercicio para trabajar con arrays, imagino que lo que quieren es que recorras el array buscando "manualmente" el más corto. Por otro lado, venir aquí a pedir cosas sin enseñar lo que has hecho no va a conseguirte nada, porque ni somos adivinos para ver qué has hecho exactamente ni vemos muy bien que la gente pida cosas sin haberse esforzado primero. Inténtalo, investiga un poco, pica algo de código y si tienes un error concreto, ven y pregunta. Te aseguro que tendrás ayuda más que suficiente... si sigues las reglas :)

Comment: Las respuestas de la publicación vinculada te pueden dar pie a construir la solución al problema expuesto

Comment: Disculpa, creo que es la segunda vez o tercera que he preguntado algo por aquí desde que he empezado a estudiar desarrollo y se me ha pasado poner el código. Llevo un tiempo leyendo e intentando probar varias opciones según lo que leo, pero no doy con ello. No se de que deduces que no me he esforzado, creo que no he indicado cuantas horas llevo con el mismo ejercicio. No pretendía ofender desde luego, solo intento estudiar.

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, es lo que buscaba!